# Passing session keys in a request body instead of cookies

Tags: session, authentication, web-applications, clojure, ring

What's the best way to accept session tokens in the request body instead of as a cookie? I basically want the functionality of `ring.middleware.session` but without using cookies because it's an API that will be called from another domain.

Are there existing examples/libraries/`cemerick.friend` workflows that do this?

Answer (score 1):

Would it be too much of a hack to put a middleware function before `ring.middleware.session` and after something like `compojure.handler.api` which copies the parameter into the session cookie. You could also wrap ring.middleware.session with your own function which puts the token where middleware.session expects it.

Comment: Can't think of any issues with it off the top of my head. Hopefully others can comment on this as well.

Comment: One caveat: tokens don't automatically expire like cookies do, so you'd have to implement that as well.